Why am I getting SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument for my box_no_counter?
I was busy coding a program (not yet done) when I encountered this  SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument. Why am I having this error?
Here is my code for reference:
def get_R_and_C_from_RandCstr(R_and_C_str: str):
    R: int = int(R_and_C_str[0])
    C: int = int(R_and_C_str[2])

    return R, C
        

def turn_grid_str_to_grid_list(grid_str: str):
    list_holder: list[int] = []
    for elem in grid_str:
        if elem.isnumeric():
            list_holder.append(int(elem))

    return list_holder

def change_right_box_no_cell(grid_list: list[list[int]], curr_box_no_cell: int, curr_row_index: int, curr_column_index: int = 0, box_no_counter: int):
    right_box_no_cell = grid_list[curr_row_index][curr_column_index + 1]
    
          
    right_box_no_cell += abs(curr_box_no_cell - right_box_no_cell - 1)
    grid_list[curr_row_index][curr_column_index + 1] = right_box_no_cell
    box_no_counter += abs(curr_box_no_cell - right_box_no_cell - 1)

    return grid_list, right_box_no_cell, box_no_counter

def change_left_box_no_cell(grid_list: list[list[int]], curr_box_no_cell: int, curr_row_index: int, curr_column_index: int = 0, box_no_counter: int):
    left_box_no_cell = grid_list[curr_row_index][curr_column_index - 1]
    
          
    left_box_no_cell += abs(curr_box_no_cell - left_box_no_cell - 1)
    grid_list[curr_row_index][curr_column_index - 1] = left_box_no_cell

    return grid_list, left_box_no_cell, box_no_counter
    
def change_up_box_no_cell(grid_list: list[list[int]], curr_box_no_cell: int, curr_row_index: int, curr_column_index: int = 0, box_no_counter: int):
    up_box_no_cell = grid_list[curr_row_index + 1][curr_column_index]
    
          
    up_box_no_cell += abs(curr_box_no_cell - up_box_no_cell - 1)
    grid_list[curr_row_index + 1][curr_column_index] = up_box_no_cell
    box_no_counter += abs(curr_box_no_cell - up_box_no_cell - 1)

    return grid_list, up_box_no_cell, box_no_counter   
    
def change_down_box_no_cell(grid_list: list[list[int]], curr_box_no_cell: int, curr_row_index: int, curr_column_index: int = 0, box_no_counter: int):
    down_box_no_cell = grid_list[curr_row_index - 1][curr_column_index]
    
          
    down_box_no_cell += abs(curr_box_no_cell - down_box_no_cell - 1)
    grid_list[curr_row_index - 1][curr_column_index] = down_box_no_cell
    box_no_counter += abs(curr_box_no_cell - down_box_no_cell - 1)

    return grid_list, down_box_no_cell, box_no_counter   

def check_if_need_to_safetify_cell(grid_list: list[list[int]], curr_row_index: int, curr_column_index: int = 0, curr_box_no_cell: int, check_this_cell: str):
    if check_this_cell == "right":
        right_box_no_cell = grid_list[curr_row_index][curr_column_index + 1]
        if (curr_box_no_cell - right_box_no_cell) > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    elif check_this_cell == "left":
        left_box_no_cell = grid_list[curr_row_index][curr_column_index - 1]
        if (curr_box_no_cell - left_box_no_cell) > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        

    elif check_this_cell == "up":
        up_box_no_cell = grid_list[curr_row_index + 1][curr_column_index]
        if (curr_box_no_cell - up_box_no_cell) > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    elif check_this_cell == "down":
        down_box_no_cell = grid_list[curr_row_index - 1][curr_column_index]
        if (curr_box_no_cell - down_box_no_cell) > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False



def safetify_the_rabbit_house(grid_list: list[list[int]]):
    box_no_counter: int = 0
    curr_box_no_cell: int = 0
    
    
    #safetify_every_row_of_rabbit_house

    for curr_row_index in range(R):
        for curr_column_index in range(C):

            if curr_row_index == 0:
                if curr_column_index == 0:
                    curr_box_no_cell = grid_list[curr_row_index][curr_column_index]

                    #check right
                    if check_if_need_to_safetify_cell(grid_list, curr_row_index, curr_column_index, curr_box_no_cell, "right"):
                        grid_list, right_box_no_cell, box_no_counter = change_right_box_no_cell(grid_list, curr_box_no_cell, curr_row_index, curr_column_index, box_no_counter)

                    #check down
                    if check_if_need_to_safetify_cell(grid_list, curr_row_index, curr_column_index, curr_box_no_cell, "down"):
                        grid_list, down_box_no_cell, box_no_counter = change_down_box_no_cell(grid_list, curr_box_no_cell, curr_row_index, curr_column_index, box_no_counter)
                    
                    
                
                else:
                    curr_box_no_cell = grid_list[curr_row_index][curr_column_index]

                    #check right
                    if check_if_need_to_safetify_cell(grid_list, curr_row_index, curr_column_index, curr_box_no_cell, "right"):
                        grid_list, right_box_no_cell, box_no_counter = change_right_box_no_cell(grid_list, curr_box_no_cell, curr_row_index, curr_column_index, box_no_counter)

                    #check down
                    if check_if_need_to_safetify_cell(grid_list, curr_row_index, curr_column_index, curr_box_no_cell, "down"):
                        grid_list, down_box_no_cell, box_no_counter = change_down_box_no_cell(grid_list, curr_box_no_cell, curr_row_index, curr_column_index, box_no_counter)

                    #check left
                    if check_if_need_to_safetify_cell(grid_list, curr_row_index, curr_column_index, curr_box_no_cell, "left"):
                        grid_list, left_box_no_cell, box_no_counter = change_left_box_no_cell(grid_list, curr_box_no_cell, curr_row_index, curr_column_index, box_no_counter)                


            

#main code

T: int = int(input())

#per test case
for i in range(T):
    R_and_C_str: str = input() #R and C input from user
    

    R, C = get_R_and_C_from_RandCstr(R_and_C_str)
    grid_list: list[list[int]] = []

    for j in range(R):
        R_line: str = input() #input the R line 
        grid_list.append(turn_grid_str_to_grid_list(R_line))
        box_no_counter: int = 0


    #grid_list = the legit grid we're working on

        safetify_the_rabbit_house(grid_list)





Here is the error:
def change_right_box_no_cell(grid_list: list[list[int]], curr_box_no_cell: int, curr_row_index: int, curr_column_index: int = 0, box_no_counter: int):
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
